# Show a toast message if the selected time range in between 9pm-9am from time-picker dialog in android?

Tags: android, timepicker, android-toast

I want to show a Toast message when a user selecting a time in between 9 PM to 9 AM from TimePicker dialog.

My Activity Code is,

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int mhour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int mminute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

mhour = hourOfDay;
mminute = minute;
updatetime(mhour,mminute);
}

 private void updatetime(int hours, int mins) {

String timeSet = "";
if (hours > 12) {
hours -= 12;
timeSet = "PM";
} else if (hours == 0) {
hours += 12;
timeSet = "AM";
} else if (hours == 12)
timeSet = "PM";
else
timeSet = "AM";
String minutes = "";
if (mins < 10)
minutes = "0" + mins;
else
minutes = String.valueOf(mins);
// Append in a StringBuilder
String aTime = new StringBuilder().append(hours).append(':')
                        .append(minutes).append(" ").append(timeSet).toString();
}
```

How to restrict the time range that i have mentioned above?